# Data from a login form not being displayed on another page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having an issue with my JavaScript code. I have a login form, and I want to send the form data to another page and display it in a table. However, the information is not being displayed on the second page.

```js
let tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");
const btnSend = document.getElementById("btnSend");
const nom = document.getElementById("nom");
const prenom = document.getElementById("prenom");
const age = document.getElementById("age");

function remplir(nom, prenom, age) {
  let tr = document.createElement("tr");
  let tdNom = document.createElement("td");
  tdNom.textContent = nom;
  let tdPrenom = document.createElement("td");
  tdPrenom.textContent = prenom;
  let tdAge = document.createElement("td");
  tdAge.textContent = age;

  let btn = document.createElement("td");
  let suppBtn = document.createElement("button");
  suppBtn.classList.add("supp");
  suppBtn.textContent = "Supp";
  btn.appendChild(suppBtn);
  let modifBtn = document.createElement("button");
  modifBtn.classList.add("modif");
  modifBtn.textContent = "Modifier";
  btn.appendChild(modifBtn);
  
  tr.appendChild(tdNom);
  tr.appendChild(tdPrenom);
  tr.appendChild(tdAge);
  tr.appendChild(btn);
  tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
btnSend.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
remplir(nom.value,prenom.value,age.value);
window.location.assign('index.html');
});
```

```css
label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  input[type="text"], input[type="number"] {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  button {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  button:hover {
    background-color: #0069d9;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Ma page principale</h1>
    <iframe src="index.html" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
    <label>Nom:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nom"  placeholder="Votre nom ici...">
    <label>Prénom:</label>
    <input type="text" id="prenom"  placeholder="Votre prénom ici...">
    <label>Âge:</label>
    <input type="number" id="age"  placeholder="Votre âge ici...">
    <button id="btnSend">Envoyer</button>
  <script src="sc.js"></script>
</body>
```

the code of the page index.html

```html
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Prénom</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Why is the data not being displayed on the second page (index.html)? How to fix this issue?

Comment: end part of your JavaScript file is missing. Can you update first.

Comment: Sorry i update file js

Comment: How are you sending the data to the server? Normally you'd use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) or the html [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) element.

Comment: sending data for show in the table

Comment: 1. you mean: pick up the data from the form, and display it on the same page without reloading? 2. what's in sc.js?

Comment: I want to show the information in table

Comment: The `remplir()` function operates on the current DOM, it can't change the DOM in `index.html`.

Comment: But it is a function and I pass it parametr

Comment: That function knows nothing about `index.html`.  Why not build your elements directly on index.html?

Comment: I want to create like CRUD

Comment: Then perhaps you should save your data to a database and then query and display it in `index.html`.

Comment: You could use localStorage to save data between the pages.

Comment: it is a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tbody.appendChild(tr); /*<- you dont have this element in your document,
its in another document so you can't access it from your login page,*/
```

you need to send that login data to the other page that has the table and hundle the diplaying function from there,

```
window.location.assign('index.html'); //<- you need to pass field values to this function
```

attach your data to this url like so -> index.html?

```
var url = `index.html?Nom=${nom.value}&prenom=${prenom.value}&age=${age.value}`
window.location.assign(url)
```

[check out how to pass data to other pages here](https://youtu.be/7BbL2PZ5394)

go to your index file, add this code

```
let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

let nom = params.get('nom');
let prenom  = params.get('prenom');
let age = params.get('age');
```

alternatively you can use localStorage wich i recommend
[see how to do it here](https://youtu.be/x0VcigW9kN0)

Comment: what didn't you undated i clarify

Comment: The link you provided doesn't work. Please update it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did a good job